# Build a static outputTable (similar to a pivot table) with shiny

Tags: shiny

I have a table that has the following data (shortened for this example):

## C1    C2    C3

1   0     1     1
2   1     1     0
3   1     0     1
4   1     1     1
5   0     0     1
6   0     0     0

I want to create a create a query that gives me the following result:

## C1

C2   sum(C3)

It's similar to a pivot table but it's static. 
Could you help me please, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Not sure what you want. Add some values, and some code that you have tried. And I think this is an R quesiton, not a Shiny question.

Comment: i'm trying to build a shiny application.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hopefully you are decent at R already because Shiny is not a beginner's R topic.

Comment: I'm a beginner in both of them, my data frame contains 3 columns: year, contributor, value. i want an output table with the years as columns, the contributers as rows and sum of values in each cell.

Comment: I'm working with shiny, I could not do it with render Table.I do not know how

Comment: publish the R code to do what you want to do.

Comment: `data <- read.csv("Z:/sinistre/mydata.csv", sep = ";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x <- as.Date(data$DATE_DE_SURVENANCE, origin="1900-01-01")
  
y <- strftime(x,"%Y")      Usage1 <- paramètres_usage$Produit[match(data$x1,paramètres_usage$code1,nomatch = 0,incomparables = NULL)]    Eval<- as.numeric(gsub(",",".",as.character(data$EVALUATION))) - as.numeric(gsub(",",".",as.character(data$EVALUATION_RECOURS)))     datax <- data.frame(Usage1,y,Eval)

dtx <- dcast(datax, Usage1 ~ y, value.var = "Eval", fun.aggregate = sum) `      that does not work

Comment: You can edit your question you know. You can't expect people to figure out that comment.

Comment: Yes I think so too. but i could not find how to return to the line so it becomes clearer

Comment: What does that mean "return to line"? Is it that hard to edit your post? Curious, I have noticed a few new users having trouble with that.

Comment: Frankly I found difficulties.

Comment: I will publish hereunder my code line by line.

Comment: `data <- read.csv("Z:/sinistre/mydata.csv", sep = ";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: `x <- as.Date(data$DATE_DE_SURVENANCE, origin="1900-01-01")`

Comment: `y <- strftime(x,"%Y")`

Comment: No, please put it in the post. It is not that hard.

Comment: `Usage1 <-paramètres_usage$Produit[match(data$x1,paramètres_usage$code‌​1,nomatch = 0,incomparables = NULL)]`

Comment: You need to learn how to do it to use this site. Millions of people have suceeded at it, I am sure you can too.

Comment: Sure i can do it , juste because my question is urgent, i could not progress

Comment: It goes fast. A simple copy and paste, and then a bit of editing.

Comment: ok i will focus a little bit.meanwhile, i have to thank you for always being there